# SELECT * FROM is not working properly with string from php code

Tags: php, mysql

I have weird problem with my code. Everything works fine until this:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE result="normal"
```

This string can't be found. It's inserted successfully into database, though. It can't be found even directly from MySQL command line. However, when I insert one more string to my table directly from MySQL command line, not from code, it can be found (but only from command line too, search from code fails). I think it has something to do with charset, but, as you see, I already used utf-8 everywhere!

```
<?PHP
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
?>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<?php

mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

require_once 'login.php';
$db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);

if (!$db_server)
    die(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($db_database) or die(mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query('CREATE TABLE test (id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT KEY, script_name VARCHAR(25), start_time INT, end_time INT, result VARCHAR(16)) ENGINE MyISAM');





for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {

    $input     = array(
        'normal',
        'illegal',
        'failed',
        'success'
    );
    $rand_keys = array_rand($input, 1);
    $a         = $input[$rand_keys] . "\n";


    $insert = rand();


    $query   = "INSERT INTO test VALUES" . "('$insert', '$insert', '$insert', '$insert', '$a')";
    $result2 = mysql_query($query);

}



$query2 = 'SELECT * FROM test WHERE result = "success"';
$result3 = mysql_query($query2);

if($result3 === FALSE) { 
echo "Oops!";
}

$rows = mysql_num_rows($result3);

for ($j = 0; $j < $rows; $j++) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    echo <<<_END
<pre>
id: $row[0]
script name: $row[1]
start: $row[2]
end: $row[3]
result: $row[4]
</pre>

_END;


}
?>
```

Comment: You are concating `\n` to your `result` values -> `$a = $input[$rand_keys] . "\n";`, so when you insert them, `"INSERT INTO test VALUES" . "('$insert', '$insert', '$insert', '$insert', '$a')";`, `normal` has a line break, so `SELECT * FROM test WHERE result="normal"` will not match. Try `SELECT * FROM test WHERE result="normal%"`

Comment: Stop using the `mysql` PHP extension. It is deprecated and it will be removed in the (not so far) future. Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
$a = $input[$rand_keys] . "\n";
                        ^^^^^^ why?
```

You will never find an exact match for any of the words you are randomly inserting as you are adding `\n` to the end of each one.

You probably want:

```
$a = $input[$rand_keys];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use 'mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());' instead of just 'mysql_query($query2);' it will help you debug.